# Azure App Registration and (ConfidentialClientApplication) returns Account NULL and Token not working for querying GraphApi (401)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm using the following code in a console application to identify it as registered azure app.

```cs
        //https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows
        var currentClaims = ClaimsPrincipal.Current; //currentClaims null
        var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(settings.ClientId)
        .WithClientSecret(settings.ClientSecret)
        .WithTenantId(settings.TenantId)
        .WithAuthority(new Uri(settings.Authority))
        .Build();
        app.AddInMemoryTokenCache();
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        AccessToken? _accessToken = null;
        try
        {
            result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes: new[] { settings.ScopeApplicationIDURI })   //api://ConsoleApp1AppRegistrationAzure/.default
                .ExecuteAsync();
            _accessToken = new AccessToken(result.AccessToken, result.ExpiresOn);
        }
        catch (MsalServiceException ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("AADSTS70011"))
        {
            // Invalid scope. The scope has to be of the form "https://resourceurl/.default"
            // Mitigation: change the scope to be as expected
        }
```

Acquireing the token works and I receive the following result like:

| Variable | Content | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| result | {Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult} |  |
| AccessToken | "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1....tg" | string |
| Account | null | Microsoft.Identity.Client.IAccount |
| AuthenticationResultMetadata | {Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResultMetadata} |  |
| ClaimsPrincipal | null | System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal |
| CorrelationId | {6cdf59da-632c-4cbd-b1f3-5cb615a87391} | System.Guid |
| ExpiresOn | {3/5/2022 3:27:51 PM +00:00} | System.DateTimeOffset |
| ExtendedExpiresOn | {3/5/2022 3:27:51 PM +00:00} | System.DateTimeOffset |
| IdToken | null | string |
| IsExtendedLifeTimeToken | false | bool |
| Scopes | Count = 1 | System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable |
| SpaAuthCode | null | string |
| TenantId | null | string |
| TokenType | "Bearer" | string |
| UniqueId | null | string |

However, why is `result.Account` null? Shouldn't I receive an account with a claim with `access_as_application`. This is how the app looks like in Azure:

[image]

How can I recieve with `result.Account` an account with the claims.

Also, querying the graph api or my app configuration (where my app has a reader role) returns 401 when using the access token.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Accept: application/json
Authorization: bearer eyJ0eXAi...
```

[Edit]
Thanks to @Gaurav Mantri, I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token which solves the second part of the question.

Comment: Regarding the 401 error for Graph API, this is because you’ve not acquired the token for Graph API.

Comment: @briefkasten did you ever figure out why Account is null and how to fix that? I'm running into the same issue. I did get an AccessToken but my AuthenticationResult.Account is null.

Comment: @Luke I think this is by design. I guess we need to send claims like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims and then set the retrieved claims/user on the current principal user. I didn't finish the task since I ran out of time